# Laravel 5.1 contract class does not exist

Tags: php, laravel, interface, laravel-5.1

I'm trying to utilize the Laravel database contract instead of the facade (DB::table) and getting:

```
ReflectionException

Class Illuminate\Contracts\Database does not exist
```

Using the `Illuminate\Database\DatabaseManager` class works fine, but I would prefer not use a concrete class but rather an abstract class (contract/interface) in addition to dependency injection.

Here's what I've tried.

Controller:

```
<?php namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Contracts\Database as DB;

class MyController extends Controller
{

    public function __construct(DB $db)
    {
        $this->db = $db;
    }

}
```

AppServiceProvider:

```
public function register()
    {
        $this->app->bind(
            'Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Registrar',
            'App\Services\Registrar',
            'Illuminate\Contracts\Database'
        );
    }
```

Any help appreciated!

Comment: You can add another facade but __construct (DB at your controller is really bad idea.. And I wonder why you decide that there is Illuminate\Contracts\Database for usage ?

Comment: `Illuminate\Contracts\Database` is not available in laravel contracts

Comment: see list of available contracts here: http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/contracts

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That Contract does not exist unless you added it yourself. `Illuminate\Contracts\Redis\Database` exists, but not what you are trying to use.

As for a Solution, I generally inject the `Illuminate\Database\DatabaseManager` class instead, which I believe is the class you are trying to get anyway. That class implements the `Illuminate\Database\ConnectionResolverInterface` interface.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out that Illuminate\Database\DatabaseManager DOES implement an interface! That's what I wanted.